# Best ftp server for ubuntu server 10.04?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ftp

Could you please recommend best ftp server for ubuntu server 10.04

Regards,
Alexey Zakharov.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should add to your question details of what you are providing a file transfer service for. Different servers have features that may be better for particular use cases.

If you are providing the services so your users can upload content and your users don't specifically need the FTP protocol, also consider the SFPC/SCP protocols provided by OpenSSH. These have advantages of over most standard implementations of FTP:

1. security: all content is transferred through an encrypted channel
2. security: even authentication credentials are securely transferred (with FTP they are usually send in plain text)
3. networking: the separate control and data connections used by FTP can be a hassle for some firewall arrangements
4. speed/bandwidth: if the user selects the option (it isn't on by default as it isn't appropriate in all cases) all data is compressed which can make quite a difference if they are uploading compressible content over a slow link
5. speed: FTP is inefficient for lots of small files (though the difference is not significant for larger files or small numbers of files)

There are several command line clients available in just about all unix-a-like OSs (graphical ones easily available too, sometimes available by default or integrated into the main filemanager) and there are good clients for Windows too ([WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php) or [FileZilla](http://filezilla-project.org/), both of which are available as [portable apps](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet)).

Obviously if you are setting up an FTP service for people to download from SFTP or SCP are probably not suitable (but I would use HTTP(S) for that instead these days) and not all Windows users will be able/willing to install a new client application (though the availability of "portable" clients reduces this potential issue a little).

**Edit:** one other advantage is that you probably already have OpenSSH installed and configured to allow SFTP/SCP for correctly authenticated users, so you have no need to add and manage a new service.

Comment: I find WinSCP best choice for me, since our dev machines a Windows-based.

Comment: FileZilla has Windows builds available too, though I use WinSCP myself under Windows and haven't had reason to look elsewhere as it has always done the job required of it.

Answer (score 5):

[vsftpd](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/vsftpd), [ProFTPd](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/proftpd) and [Pure-FTPd](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/pure-ftpd)
 are all good and proven FTP servers which are available in Ubuntu Linux 10.04.

Just pick the one which fits your requirements best.

Comment: thumbs up for pureftpd - simple to set up, can have virtual accounts configured via mysql.

Comment: We have used vsftpd very successfully.

Answer (score 1):

ProFTPD is the best for me.

Answer (score 1):

[vsftpd](https://security.appspot.com/vsftpd.html) ("Very Secure FTP Daemon") is also good for Linux because it's very fast.